# Use the gif image in the manifest file icons

Tags: reactjs, image, progressive-web-apps, animated-gif, manifest.json

I am developing an application using reactjs. I want to use a gif instead of a png image when the user opens the program via shourtcut. I have also defined the manifest file as follows, but instead of an animated image, a fix image is displayed. Is this method correct for displaying the animated image or should it be done in another way?

```
{
"short_name": "Sample",
"name": "Sample Project",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "Icons/iconImage.gif",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/gif"
    },
    {
        "src": "Icons/iconImage.gif",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/gif"
    },
    {
        "src": "Icons/iconImage.gif",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/gif"
    },
    {
        "src": "Icons/iconImage.gif",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/gif"
    },
    {
        "src": "Icons/iconImage.gif",
        "sizes": "168x168",
        "type": "image/gif"
    }
],
"start_url": "./index.html",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#4285F4",
"background_color": "#ffffff"
```

}